# Wrong tibble printout in R VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, rstudio, tibble

I have recently had to reset my PC. After reinstalling VSCode, packages and dependencies, I have started to run R code as usual. However, the printout that I get from tibbles in the R console seems quite weird, here is an example of the iris dataset as a tibble:

```r
> tibble::as_tibble(iris)
[38;5;246m# A tibble: 150 × 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>                                                                        m<dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa
 3          4.7         3.2                          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa
 7                          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa
10          4.9         3.1                          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# ℹ 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

This doesn't happen in RStudio though, nor with `data.table` or `data.frame`.

Has anyone had the same problem before?